# How to put one abstract class in another in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

It is actually a design question.
Lets say I have an interface *a* and a class *aa* with abstract methods *m1*, *m2*, and it inherits from *a*.

```
public interface a
{
  string m1();
  string m2();
}

public abstract class aa:a
{
  public abstract string m1();
  public abstract string m2();
}
```

I also have a different interface *b* and a class *bb* that inherits from it.

```
public interface b
{
  string n1();
  string n2();
}

public abstract class bb:b
{
  public abstract string n1();
  public abstract string n2();
}
```

And I want to force the class that inherits *aa* to implement the methods of class *bb* (same as it have to implement *m1* and *m2*)

What is the correct way of doing it?

```
public abstract class aa:a
{
  public abstract string m1();
  public abstract string m2();
  public abstract bb()?? 
  or public abstract bb.n1()???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of these: *Inherit* aa from bb class; *Implement* b interface in aa class; 
*Implement* b interface in aa class *explicitly*:

```
// Inherit aa from bb class
public abstract class aa:a, bb {
  public abstract string m1();
  public abstract string m2();

  // public abstract string n1(); // <- From bb class
  // public abstract string n2(); // <- From bb class
}

// Implement b interface in aa class
public abstract class aa:a, b {
  public abstract string m1();
  public abstract string m2();

  public abstract string n1(); // <- From b interface
  public abstract string n2(); // <- From b interface
}

// Implement b interface in aa class explicitly
public abstract class aa:a, b {
  public abstract string m1();
  public abstract string m2();

  protected abstract string core_n1(); // <- Put (override) b interface implementation here
  protected abstract string core_n2(); // <- Put (override) b interface implementation here

  // Can't be abstract itself but can call an abstract method
  b.string n1() { // <- explicit implementation, mo public or other modifier here!
    return core_n1();
  }
  // Can't be abstract itself but can call an abstract method
  b.string n2() { // <- explicit implementation, mo public or other modifier here!
    return core_n2();
  }
}
```

Comment: In the first option, I didn't write n1 and n2, it got it automatically from the inheritance... If I DO write it, he will know it is related to bb? he won't think it's aa's method?

Comment: @user990635 I'm very sorry: you are quite right, you should not put n1() as well as n2() explicitly in the 1st case. In order to re-declare (not recommended) a method you should put it like "public new string n1();"

Comment: thanks a lot :) btw, which one is better? 1st or 2nd? (I mean in terms of correct design)

Comment: @user990635 that depends on your requirements, the first solution uses class inheritance, the second one the interface...